# autohotkey radio button exclusivity

Tags: radio-button, toggle, autohotkey

I'm not a programmer, but I'm in need of some help with an AutoHotkey script please.

My form has 4 radio buttons labeled 'now' 'next' 'someday' 'whenever'.
I need to make sure that only 1 of the buttons is selected at a time.  If 'now' is selected then I select 'next', the 'now' button should automatically deselect.

```
Gui, Add, Radio, x100 y47 w100 h20 vnow, Now
Gui, Add, Radio, x220 y47 w100 h20 vnext, Next
Gui, Add, Radio, x340 y47 w100 h20 vsomeday, Someday
Gui, Add, Radio, x460 y47 w100 h20 vwhenever, Whenever
```

How do I do this in AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you describe is the default for radio buttons.  You are simply missing a `Gui, Show` line at the end of your script.